# Are there any multi-database multi-tenant ASP.Net MVC reference applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I'm currently building a multi-tenant, single code-base MVC app hosted on Windows Azure and have come up with my own application framework work to support it.

Although it works I'm still not a 100% happy with it and I was wondering if anyone knew of a good example of multi-database,single code base out there ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the multitenancy, but [KiGG](http://kigg.codeplex.com/) is really nice example of domain driven design and application supporting multiple databases. It doesn't use multiple databases at the same time, but they way the layers are designed allows very nice extensibility, for example for caching or logging.

I think the design approach of KiGG is very good for multitenancy too, and even if it doesn't answer your question completely, I think it is worth of reading the code anyway.